# Iterative methods for underestimate of smallest eigenvalue for large sparse matrices

Tags: linear-solver, sparse-matrix, eigenvalues

I recently read the paper "EUCLIDEAN-NORM ERROR BOUNDS FOR SYMMLQ AND CG" by Estrin et al. and there they use an underestimate (i.e. something in $(0,\lambda_{min}]$) of the smallest eigenvalue of the matrix in order to derive a practical upper bound for the L2 error of the iterations.

In my case I am dealing with very large and sparse matrices, and I would like to find such an underestimate for the smallest eigenvalue in order to be able to apply the above method. Is there some algorithm that is considered state of the art in that regard? What I am aware of is the inverse power iteration however it requires solving a sequence of problems with the system matrix which is not very fast, and I also do not know what the precision guarantees are or whether I am guaranteed to get an underestimate of the eigenvalue. I also looked into Saad's book, but there weren't very many details on this specific problem.